# Usage of Async and await in Angular Subscribe for http get

Tags: angular

Am using Subscriber in Angular 7 app, invoked API, API response will have JSON response and also some time it has plain text. how do I know response has JSON or Plain text

Tried with response headers Content-Type: application/json, for JSON and text we get Same content type.

response structure  when JSON - res.dataset.data.record.
response text - "No data found, please check with ....."

When response has JSON, need to show in table
when text response show alert.

How can i differentiate the response.

```
this._scenarioService.searchScenarioResults().subscribe(
      async res => {  
          console.log("Response ty[pe"+res.type);
      this.resultSet = res.dataset.data.record;
      this.columnHeader = Object.keys(this.resultSet[0]);
      await this.data.changeSearchResultset(this.columnHeader,this.resultSet);
      this.data.changeMessage(true);
      },
      err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
```

Comment: {
  "dataset": {
    "data": {
      "record": [
        {
          "BAN":

Comment: When the response is `No data found, please check with...` is the response status code the same (200)? Is there any way to change the server to specify the correct content-type or return a 404 status which would be more appropriate?

Comment: Back end is not ready to change and status 200 for both case. Need to handle something with response type etc..

Comment: Validate first type of response by : if ( typeof  res == "string" ) {} else {}

Comment: Thanks @YasserMas, It worked

Comment: Can you look async and await , the way i used is proper one or not.   The reason i used Async is to avoid next execution before API call completes.  @YasserMas

Comment: it looks nice, does changeSearchResultset returns a http promise , if you would like to handle http rejection response by try catch block